# Meteor accounts-password + accounts-entry and Password Confirmation

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I don't see any options in the accounts-entry package, nor the accounts-password package, that allows for a password-confirmation field in the signup form in accounts-entry. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked around and the solution I ultimately landed on was to use a different package. I used the [joshowens:accounts-entry](https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry) package, I'd recommend it to anybody.

Comment: But this doesn't support password confirmation either - not described in the documentation at least...

Comment: it might well be the case that this was a feature at some earlier point in time but has now gone away. it's been a while since I was in the meteor world, sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 3):

No it dosnt have a verify password field on the package, you need to create by your own with simple JS

```
if(password === validationPassword){
  Meteor.call("createUsers",mail,password,profile);
}
```

This type of action can only be completed in the client side and not on the server side, because the password that the user type is sent to the server `(hashed)`, so we cant make any server validation.

I think with a simple `if (===)` its ok, And Also the easy way

Comment: Don't EVER send password through wire, Accounts.createUser is also on client side and it takes care to change it into SHA256