# How can I modify the Meteor Accounts package to require the user to verify password during registration?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

Is there a way to require a password match before the user can be successfully registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094316/meteor-accounts-password-accounts-entry-and-password-confirmation), there is no option to do this in the standard Meteor Accounts packages; you can either:

- use the solution given there, or
- use the excellent Meteor UserAccounts packages, which let you configure "confirm password" in the options (see [here](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#options))